# How to call operator template?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I am feeling a bit confused about how to instantiate this template. I know it is gonna be easier to simply use `friend` membership to realize what I want, but what if I force to do in this way? I just wanna figure it out. (And btw, I know this template seems meaningless), I just want to make it compile.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const T& date)
{
    os << date.getD() << " " << date.getM() << " " << date.getY() << "\n";
    return os;
}

class Date 
{
private:
    int dd, mm, yy;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y) : dd(d), mm(m), yy(y) {}
    int getD() const;
    int getM() const;
    int getY() const;
};

int Date::getD() const {  return dd; }

int Date::getM() const {  return mm; }

int Date::getY() const {  return yy; }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Date dat(1, 2, 2003);
    std::cout << <Date> dat;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're declaring `operator<<` as template that could accept any types; which would lead to ambiguity issue with `std::operator<<`.
2. You can't specify template argument explicitly when calling the operator in *operator* style. (You can do it in ugly *function* style like `operator<< <Date>(std::cout, dat);`) Actually you don't need to specify it, the template parameter could be deduced fine here.

You can change the code to

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Date& date) {
    os << date.getD() << " " << date.getM() << " " << date.getY() <<"\n";
    return os;
}
```

then

```
Date dat(1,2,2003);
std::cout << dat;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RakxplXMDej3Qrty)

Answer (score 4):

> but what if I force to do in this way?

As others mentioned, you do not need a template here. But if you insist to do it by templates, you can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to the templated overload of `operator<<`.

**([See live here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MzyejNQdp0dma6U8))**

```
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_same

template <typename T>
auto operator<< (std::ostream& os, const T& date)
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Date, T>, std::ostream&>
{
    os << date.getD() << " " << date.getM() << " " << date.getY() << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to ever do this though? Like maybe if it were part of a larger class, and only wanted the ability to print out a `Date` or something?

Comment: @Tas If you "insist to over-engineer the simple things",  yes..  that is the only reason!

Answer (score 3):

This will be done automatically by the compiler. Simply do

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Date dat(1,2,2003);
    std::cout << dat;
    return 0;
}
```

This is done with [ADL (Argument-dependent lookup)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: I tried automatically type deduction, but the compiler will report ' use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const char [2]')'

Comment: This is a different issue you have. And @songyuanyao have just answered it.